# Bootstrap 3 input-group-addon suffix not attached to form field

Tags: c#, css, twitter-bootstrap

Using Bootstrap 3 as part of an C# ASP.NET MVC5 project.

I'm getting a very strange issue when trying to use input-group-addon to add a 'GB' suffix to a form field.

Here's the C#:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.capacity, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <div class="input-group">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.capacity, new { @class = "form-control" })
                    <span class="input-group-addon">GB</span>
                </div>
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.capacity)
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
        
}
```

Which equates to:

```
    <form action="/NewSpaceRequest/Create" method="post"><input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="tP5XKKhflSS8K1e7q1I_ZSuR8Ty7X88FfuOMG5JhmF-KXtUOcn4SQdNGTMZZVC2pdBMjb7RgNrIB90Y9I5C_FgX9xmMLrwrbiFZde7PRZ13gCqjBDAVglM38T7j09-C-uNkRSCZbFqDgiU_XcH9D-w2" />
<div class="form-horizontal">
            <hr />

            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="capacity">Capacity</label>
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Capacity must be a number." data-val-range="The field Capacity must be between 1 and 2147483647." data-val-range-max="2147483647" data-val-range-min="1" data-val-required="The Capacity field is required." id="capacity" name="capacity" type="text" value="" />
                        <span class="input-group-addon">GB</span>
                    </div>
                    <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="capacity" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

[image: And I end up with this, in Chrome on Windows]

Notice how the suffix isn't 'pulled left' to the form field?

Not sure why.

Comment: I've tested your html in the [this plunker](http://embed.plnkr.co/6yOUlskYO9PpYiDJ7IVH/preview), works fine. Could you check in browser what additional styles are applied to that element? it might be the case, that you set the fixed width for the input

Comment: You're completely right. I didn't even realise it but MVC5 comes with its own styles on top of bootstrap, one of each sets the max width of inputs to 280px.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The framework stack (ASP.NET, MVC5) comes with additional styles on top of Bootstrap, found in Site.css, which statically sets the maximum with of input fields.

You can safely remove this entire entry.

Upon doing this, your form fields will be super long. To remedy this, I changed `col-md-10` to something shorter like `col-md-4`, works a treat.

Comment: Great answer! I've been going over my code and bootstrap documentation for hours to find the reason behind the issue, your answer solved it in no time :)